# Trying to get back the JasperPrint as return Type form Server

Tags: java, jasper-reports, resttemplate

I have a server side code as

```
    @POST
    @Path("/getJasperPrint")
    public  JasperPrint getReport(ReportMapper reportMapper,@Context HttpServletRequest request,@Context  HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, reportMap,
                        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb" + "?user=" + "admin" + "&password=" + "admin"));
return jasperPrint ;
}
```

I am trying to access this with RestTemplate as

```
  RestTemplate abc = new RestTemplate();
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = abc.postForObject("http://localhost:8008/report/getJasperPrint", objectA, JasperPrint.class);
```

It gives the error

```
no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class path to jasperPrint].
```

Anything I need to do here .

Answer (score 0):

### Spring Source Blog Post

> Objects passed to and returned from the methods getForObject(), postForLocation(), and put() and are converted to HTTP requests and from HTTP responses by HttpMessageConverters.

What i think is you need to write your own convertor in order to get response as jasperprint